# How to Register mouserover on elements from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to register the mouseover event on the elements that are generated AFTER user click the button.

The elements are generated via ajax. The mouserover doesn't seem to work on the elements that ajax created. I was wondering if there are ways to work around this. Thanks a lot.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://list.php", 
        data: null, 
        dataType:"json", 
              timeout: 10000,
              global: true,
              error: oh_no,
        success: 
     });

var image = document.getElementById('image');

the image path are from ajax.

function listem(){
 ......codes
 ......codes

 image.innerHTML=  image.innerHTML + "<img src="\" + imagePath + \"\>";
} 

$(document).ready(function(){   


   $('#image img').mouseover(function(){

       alert('mouseOVER!!!');

   });

})





html    

<button id='showstuff' onclick='listem();'>show</button>
```

Comment: You need to inject jquery in element created via ajax. That will be done with .live() function or livequery plugin. See links for live http://api.jquery.com/live/ and for livequery http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: Shuld i put it as an answer if it works?

Answer (score 1):

Also you're applying the listeners on page load, but the objects don't exist at that point. Trying creating a function like "AddImageListeners()" and call it in the "success" portion of your ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [delegation (using `.on` method)](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You can delegate event handling to parent object:

```
 $('#image').on('click', 'img', function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply the mouseover to elements that don't exist yet, so your ready function would only apply to existing #image. Do a function on ajax success to apply the listeners and you should be good.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://list.php", 
        data: null, 
        dataType:"json", 
              timeout: 10000,
              global: true,
              error: oh_no,
        success: function(){
           $('#image img').mouseover(function(){
               alert('mouseOVER!!!');
           });
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting mouse over on your selector you need to use live,delegate or on depending on jQ version.

this means that event triggers should also be added to dynamically added content like ajax calls.

to do this use something like this.

```
$(document).ready(
  $("html").on("mouseover","yourselector", yourOnMouseFunction())
);
```

good luck (html can be replaced by any parent selector if you want live events only with in certain selectors).

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject jquery in element created via ajax. That will be done with `.live()` function, `.on()` function or `livequery` plugin. See links for `.live()` [api.jquery.com/live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and for `livequery` [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)